# Problems using the jQuery SVG animation plugin on a line

Tags: jquery, css, animation, svg

I've done some poking about but the documentation seems a little sparse on the subject, and one or two things aren't adding up,

**I'm trying to get a line to track an animated element, my design for this is to use the same animation variables as on the box element for the X1 co-ordinate of the line,**

Javascript (latest jQuery, SVG Plugin + SVG Animation Plugin)

```
$(function(){
var balloons = [
$("#box1"),
$("#box2"),
$("#box3")
];

var lines = [
$("#line1"),
$("#line2"),
$("#line3")
];

function act(jqObj, lineX, speed, change) {
jqObj
.animate({'left': change}, speed)
.animate({'left': -change}, speed);

lineX
.animate({svgX1: change}, speed)
.animate({sgvX1: -change}, speed, function() {
    act(jqObj, lineX, speed, change);
});
};
for (i = 0; i < balloons.length; i++) {
var speed = 2000 + Math.random() * 501;
var change = 10 + Math.random() * 26;
act(balloons[i], lines[i], speed, change);
}
});
```

HTML/CSS

```
<html>
<head>

<title>Proof of Concept Page</title>
<style type="text/css">
 .html .body {position: absolute;}

.box {
 position: absolute;
        width:100px;
        height:100px;
        position: absolute;
        background-color:red;
}
#box1 {
margin-left:300px; margin-top:60px 
}
#box2 {
margin-left:500px; margin-top:20px 
}
#box3 {
margin-left:700px; margin-top:50px 
}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.svg.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.svganim.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>


</head>
<body>
<div  class="box" id="box1">Proj 1</div>
<div  class="box" id="box2">Proj 2</div>
<div  class="box" id="box3">Proj 3</div>

<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">
    <line id="line1" x1="350" y1="160" x2="550" y2="500" style="stroke:rgb(255,0,0);stroke-width:2"/>
    <line id="line2" x1="550" y1="120" x2="550" y2="500" style="stroke:rgb(255,0,0);stroke-width:2"/>
    <line id="line3" x1="750" y1="150" x2="550" y2="500" style="stroke:rgb(255,0,0);stroke-width:2"/>
</svg>

</body></html>
```

There are a few problems here, firstly, the obvious one, which is that the current code sets the position of the X1 to the far left because I'm not telling to add to the original value.

The reason I'm not using **'+=change'** is that **'+=anything'** breaks the code for some reason, even a generic numerical value.

Finally, even if I just set the value of the first X1 animation to say 500, and the second to 0, only the first will fire, the second animation is being skipped. This effect is seen here too where the lines fly to the far left and then **don't move**.

I'm sure this is partly my extremely amateur understanding of jQuery and Javascript, but I would appreciate any constructive help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was rather challenging in that I had not used svg before.

After playing with it on and off for a couple of days, I ended up with this:

```
var $boxes = $(".box"),//coded in HTML
    strings = [];//populated below with sgv lines

$('#canvas').svg({
    onLoad: function(svg) {
        var g = svg.group({
            stroke: 'red',
            strokeWidth: 2
        });
        $boxes.each(function(i, el) { // make one string per box.
            strings.push(svg.line(g, parseInt($(el).css('left')), 18+parseInt($(el).css('top')), 50, 200));
        });
    }
});

//animate the boxes
$boxes.each(function(i, el) {
    var speed = 2000 + Math.random() * 501,
        change = 10 + Math.random() * 26,
        jqObj = $(el),
        initial_left = parseInt(jqObj.css('left')) || 0;
    (function act() {
        jqObj.animate({
            'left': initial_left + change
        }, {
            duration: speed,
            step: function() { //move the string's top end to keep up with the box
                $(strings[i]).animate({
                    svgX1: jqObj.css('left')
                }, 0);
            }
        }).animate({
            'left': initial_left - change
        }, {
            duration: speed,
            step: function() { //move the string's top end to keep up with the box
                $(strings[i]).animate({
                    svgX1: jqObj.css('left')
                }, 0);
            },
            complete: act
        });
    })();
});
```

See [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/a2r3L/2/).

This is actually a hybrid solution with svg strings and non-svg text boxes. These elements are animated in such a way that each string appears to be attached to a text box.

The code is not easy to follow and could no doubt be simplified. In the end, I was just pleased to get something working. Good education for me and I hope it's useful to you .

EDIT - explanatory notes:

**Your interpretation**: Just about correct. I'm actually using an alternative form of animate, which works as follows, `.animate(properties, options)`, where properties and options are both maps (javascript objects). This form of the method allows a `step` option to be specified - ie. an operation that will occur at each step of the animation. In this case, the operation of interest is changing the position of the top end of the balloon string.

**`i` and 'el'**: jQuery's `.each()` methods offer a convenient way to iterate over the elements in an array, the DOM nodes in a jQuery container, or properties of a plain js object. Both forms of `.each()` accept a callback function which specifies the operation to perform at *each* iteration. In turn, the callback function accepts two parameters representing (for array and jQuery container) `index` and `value`, or (for plain js object) `key` and `value`. The `.each()` method calls the callback function internally and inserts the parameters once per iteration. When writing a callback, you can call the arguments what you like, and I called them `i` (short for `index`) and `el` (short for element).

**Line animation**: The line actually DOES just move a tiny bit and stop. BUT, this operation is performed in the `step` callback, it is called once per step of the animation - ie. as many times as necessary until the animation is complete. Thus, the line keeps up with the object to which it is "glued".

Comment: Wow that's incredible thank you! It'll take me a while to understand it all but I hope I do in the end.

Comment: Actually I was able to follow that through, correct me if I'm wrong, but the first function produces a canvas and a sting for each box, with one point identical to the initial box position and the other at an arbitrary position. 

THEN the second function animates the boxes and sneaks into the speed variable an extra function to change the X1 position of the relevant line to exactly the current position of the box at maximum speed. 

TWO things I don't understand are the use of el and i, and why the animation of the line doesn't just move a tiny bit to the current position of the box and stop?

Comment: OK, I will have tried to explain in an edit to the answer - too long for a comment.

Comment: Oh I see, they're required by the .each API.

Comment: Oliver, not required - there's no obligatgion to use these parameters passed to the callback but they are always made available by `.each()` and are very convenient in many situations.

Comment: Ha! You are an absolute legend! Beetroot-Beetroot thank you so much :)